# Metabase - WHERE field IN clause

Tags: python, sql, metabase

I am using Metabase to embed graphs in my application, sending signed parameters. Now I need to have a question with a WHERE clause with multiple values, like this:

`select * from table where field in ('a', 'b', 'c')`

So far I was only able to put in scalar values. But now I need those values to come from a list. Is this achievable?

EDIT:

I was able to hack it by:

1) create a string with those values quoted
`quoted_values = '"a", "b", "c"'`

2) in the SQL of the question, have:
`WHERE field in ({{quoted_values}})`

Still, not very clean

Comment: Can you create a view with this query in db, and make Metabase use this view instead of table?

Comment: Which database will this run on, or does it need to be portable?